# Mac Autoresize NSView Keep Aspect Ratio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

I have code that keeps my main window in its respective aspect ratio when the user resizes it. (using windowWillResize delegate method)  I have some subviews of that window that I also want to keep at their own aspect ratios.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should start by looking at `-resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:`, [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resizeWithOldSuperviewSize%3a) thus:

> Informs the receiver that the bounds size of its superview has changed.